# new found IsNullOrEmpty bug?

Tags: isnullorempty

below is in a async call and

if (args[0]).ToString() return null,  first { will never be reached, and thread seem disapear or blocked.

if (args[0]).ToString() return "", all just behave normal.

```
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty( (args[0]).ToString()) )
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `args[0]` is null, `.ToString()` will throw a `NullReferenceException` before you get to call `IsNullOrEmpty()` on its result.